# Selenium StoreText invalid xpath[2] error

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I am new to selenium.
I tried to save  a text from the xpath using storeText and the target is //*[@id='mathq2'].
the base URL is http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/.

I am getting this error

```
[info] Executing: |storeText | //*[@id='mathq2'] | wwww |
[error] Invalid xpath [2]: //*[@id='mathq2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Danny got the same error in timesof india website. This is what i did.

I recorded the element (by entering something in the text box next to it) then clicked on the value like `8+0 =` and then selected the radio button above it.
So my selenium showed

```
click    id=mathq2
```

from there i chose the xpath in the Target dropdown and the xPath seemed to show

```
//span[@id='mathq2']
```

so finally I replaced my step for storeText as

storeText  `//span[@id='mathq2']`   addition

and then it stored that value 8+0 = in the variable 'addition'.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error, because there is no element with such xPath at the main page of http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/.
Why do you think it is there?

You can use xPath Checker (Firefox plugin) to check if the xPath is proper and the element exists.

Answer (score 0):

yes, ID is there, but text is changing dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the xpath= prefix in your target, and it seems that the xpath is also prepended with a period:

```
|storeText | xpath=.//*[@id='mathq2'] | wwww |
```

You would also need to ensure that your script waits for the initial advertisement page to unload.

Comment: The XPath `//*[@id='mathq2']` is different from `.//*[@id='mathq2']`. If you write the latter, that is not just “prepending” the XPath, it limits the scope.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Christopher!

Comment: Rohit, since the id is dynamic, we'd need to single out the element using some other means.  Is this element always contained within the following location: .//*[@id='pollform']/table/tbody       I also noticed that the following xpath also represents the same area:  .//*[@id='pdiv']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]